# JSON listview OnItemClickListener url open in WebView

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, onclicklistener

I have an activity that fetches content from a JSON URL and displays the contents in a list view.

The contents include images, URL of the post, description etc. Each content item has its own URL.

I want to open it in another activity which has a WebView.

This is MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
private static final String JSON_URL = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/radiotracer133/f9c5abf2c1fb403c4091ff7bc2ed8845/raw/78b956f078191c3f4b6c2c9c27f92da7ada2f7b4/example.json";
//the tutorial list where we will store all the tutorial objects after parsing json
List<Books> booksList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    booksList = new ArrayList<>();
    //this method will fetch and parse the data
    loadTutorialList();
}

private void loadTutorialList() {
    //getting the progressbar
    final ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    //creating a string request to send request to the url
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, JSON_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    //hiding the progressbar after completion
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                    try {
                        //getting the whole json object from the response
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

                        //we have the array named tutorial inside the object
                        //so here we are getting that json array
                        JSONArray tutorialsArray = obj.getJSONArray("Books");

                        //now looping through all the elements of the json array
                        for (int i = 0; i < tutorialsArray.length(); i++) {
                            //getting the json object of the particular index inside the array
                            JSONObject tutorialsObject = tutorialsArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            //creating a books object and giving them the values from json object
                            Books books = new Books(tutorialsObject.getString("Name"), tutorialsObject.getString("image"),tutorialsObject.getString("Author"), tutorialsObject.getString( "Name_url" ));

                            //adding the books to tutoriallist
                            booksList.add( books );

                        }

                        //creating custom adapter object
                        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter( booksList, getApplicationContext());

                        //adding the adapter to listview
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //displaying the error in toast if occur
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    //creating a request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //adding the string request to request queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

}
```

This is MyAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.List;


public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Books> {
//the tutorial list that will be displayed
private List<Books> booksList;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private Context mCtx;
//here we are getting the tutoriallist and context
//so while creating the object of this adapter class we need to give tutoriallist and context
public MyAdapter(List<Books> booksList, Context mCtx) {
    super(mCtx, R.layout.list_item, booksList );
    this.booksList = booksList;
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
}

//this method will return the list item
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //getting the layoutinflater
    ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null, true);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    //getting text views
    holder.textViewName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    holder.textDescription = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewImageUrl);
    holder.imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    holder.detailsView = convertView.findViewById( R.id.detailsview );

    convertView.setTag(holder);
    //Getting the books for the specified position
    Books books = booksList.get(position);
    String imageUrl = books.getImageUrl();
    String tutorialDescription = books.getDescription();
    String tutorialTitle = books.getName();
    String detailsTitle = books.getDetails();

    holder.textViewName.setText(tutorialTitle);
    holder.textDescription.setText(tutorialDescription);
    holder.detailsView.setText( detailsTitle );

    if (holder.imageView != null) {
        /*-------------fatching image------------*/;
        new ImageDownloaderTask(holder.imageView).execute(imageUrl);
    }

    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    return convertView;

}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView textViewName;
    TextView textDescription;
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView detailsView;
}
}
```

How can I implement OnclickListerner here to open WebView?

Comment: implement clicklistener to the convertView.. you can get context from viewgroup parent.Context or you can use view context as well

Comment: in viewholder, get the parent layout id and declare. then put onclicklistener for parent layout and send the url in intent to webview class.